# Where can I find CLR function text in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, function, clr

I've created an application to synchronize Microsoft SQL Server databases with the same structure. One of the tasks I need to solve is to transfer any database routine (procedure, function, trigger, etc) from source database to target one. For routine transfer I use a query

```
SELECT [definition] FROM sys.sql_modules WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('SOME_OBJECT_ID')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where routine_name like '%SOME_ROUTINE_NAME%'
```

And it works perfectly for all the routines except CLR functions (the functions with `[type_desc] = CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION` or `[type_desc] = CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION`).

Their text is not stored in `sys.sql_modules` datatable and system view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` contains values `[ROUTINE_BODY] = EXTERNAL` and `[ROUTINE_DEFINITION] = NULL`.

But I'm sure that CLR function text is not recreated every time I open it because it can be changed and saved with user changes.

So I'd be very grateful for any hint about CLR function text location.

UPDATE: I don't needed to transfer .NET library function itself, I just want to transfer the wrapper function that is created manually in Programmability > Functions > Table-valued Functions.

Comment: CLR functions are assembly(dll) created in .NET and registered in SQL server. you can get the list from assembly sys.assemblies. so you will not get the text definition for CLR function inside SQL Server.

Comment: @RahulRichhariya, I don't want to transfer CLR function (= .NET library function), I asked a question about CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION or CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION - objects you can find in Programmability > Functions > Table-valued Functions list. And you can edit and save this object like any standard function (SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION).

Comment: So, you're trying to generate the equivalent of, say, `CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[len_s] (@str nvarchar(4000))  
RETURNS bigint  
AS EXTERNAL NAME [SurrogateStringFunction].[Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SurrogateStringFunction].[LenS];`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you're quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Profiler has shown 35 different dynamic queries used by Management Studio to build the CLR wrapper function. So function text is unfortunately built on-the-fly and nothing is stored in the depths of system databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look into CLR function or procedure you need to perform some steps as CLR functions an procedures are created from assemblies.

Step-1:- Export your assemblies to file system

- Using powershell -http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/erichumphrey/2012/03/02/extract-clr-assemblies-from-sql-server/
- Bycreating another CLR assembly - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3126/exporting-clr-assemblies-from-sql-server-back-to-dll-files/

Step-2:- Use .net assembly Decompiler like http://ilspy.net/ or redgate reflector

This method will work if assembly creator has not performed addition steps to prevent de-compilation.

Comment: I don't need to transfer .NET library between databases, I want to transfer CLR wrapper function that is created in Programmability > Functions > Table-valued Functions. Please look at @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment, he's got the point.

Comment: ok got you. Are you fine with using powershell or do you want to use sql queries only?

Comment: I prefer using SQL queries but I'd be very grateful for any solution you can provide. But it sounds very strange for me that all the queries are located in `sys.sql_modules` datatable and can be easily selected and CLR wrapping queries (that look the same way and can be changed in the same way) need to be extracted using PowerShell.